# connection error with db2 jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

Can anyone offer a clue on how to diagnose the error listed below?  Note, I CAN connect to this DB2 instance via DB2 connect, but not thru jdbc.

```
   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to open a test 

connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:db2://dxxx_xxx.xxx.com:5000/XXXXX:deferPrepares=false, username = NNNNN. Terminating connection pool. Original Exception: ------
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10051][3.63.75] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2:/dxxx_xxx.xxx.com:5000/XXXXX:deferPrepares=false. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:679)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:85)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.tokenizeURLProperties(DB2Driver.java:911)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:408)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:256)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:305)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.maybeInit(BoneCPDataSource.java:150)
```

Comment: I was missing a ; at the end of the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory:

> Invalid database URL syntax

You must not have any spaces in the URL, and key-value pairs are separated with semicolons, not commas. Note that you must put a semicolon after the last value too.

```
jdbc:db2://dxxx_xxx.xxx.com:5000/XXXXX:deferPrepares=false;username=NNNNN;
```

Details can be found [in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.html).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this information taken from the DB2 documentation (added link of the reference below).

**Message text:** text-from-getMessage

**Explanation:** The specified value is invalid or out of range.

**User response:** Call SQLException.getMessage to retrieve specific information about the problem.

**SQLSTATE:** 42815

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjcsqc.html